# Creating 1 stacked column in a graph of unstacked columns

Tags: excel, excel-2010, bar-chart

Currently I have a bar chart that looks like this:

[image]

The red column is a subset of the green column (meaning that the green column is red column + some other data), so I want excel to combine them into one stacked bar with 4/5ths of the column colored red and the rest green, whilst leaving the other bars (blue, purple) as they are. How do I do this?